# PHP array keys values repeating error

Tags: php

```
I have following array :
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
    [sbu_name] => DISTRIBUTION CONSULTING
    [2016-06-26 TO 2016-07-2] => 
    [2016-06-5 TO 2016-06-11] => 
    [2016-06-19 TO 2016-06-25] => 57
)

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [sbu_name] => PMC
        [2016-06-26 TO 2016-07-2] => 467.25
        [2016-06-5 TO 2016-06-11] => 10
        [2016-06-19 TO 2016-06-25] => 
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [sbu_name] => VAI
        [2016-06-26 TO 2016-07-2] => 
        [2016-06-5 TO 2016-06-11] => 
        [2016-06-19 TO 2016-06-25] => 
    )
)
```

---

I have to print the keys in view of this array i have achieve this using below code

```
foreach ($collection as $key => $val) {
    foreach ($val as $key2 => $newVal) { ?>
        <th><?php echo $key2; ?></th>
    <?php
    }
}
```

---

but it output shows like this repeating. 
I don't want that:
[image]

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: So which values do you want to show? Currently the script is exactly doing the thing i can read out of it

Comment: What you want to display?

Comment: `foreach($val as $key2 => $newVal)` looks strange. You can't iterate over `stdClass` objects. But you can cast those into an array and then use it a loop: `foreach( (array) $val as $key2 => $newVal)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing the headers multiple times (once per result), you should only do that once:

```
<table><thead><tr>
<?php
if (is_array($collection) && count($collection) > 0) {
    $val = current($collection);
    foreach ((array)$val as $key2 => $newVal) { ?>
        <th><?php echo $key2; ?></th>
    <?php
    }
}?>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach ($collection as $key => $val) { ?>
    <tr>
    <?php 
    foreach ($val as $key2 => $newVal) { ?>
        <td><?php echo $newVal; ?></th>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr> 
   <?php
} ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hi thanx for the answer now the problem is that my headers are showing once but my <tbody> section is also showing only once and i want its shows all values can u plz help me out

Comment: There's no mention of the `tbody` in the question, nor do you provide the code that generates it. I'm just going by what I see.

Comment: yes u r right now i m stuck in <tbody> section i cannot figure out what code should i right in that section to show all values

Comment: See my edit, but in the future make sure your questions are self contained and don't require constant clarifications.

Comment: thank u so much i got my desired result and i will make sure i will be specific about my questions in future

Answer (score 0):

You are printing all as table header `th` tags. This will result in the output you show in your image. All keys will be but together on a single line.

You should to a `tr` with multiple `td` for each array element.

```
foreach ($collection as $key => $val) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ((array)$val as $key2 => $newVal) {
        echo sprintf("<td>%s</td>", $key2);
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```